# What alternatives to Google are there for searching for examples of phrases in old texts?

Tags: discussion, etymology

I have used Google for many years, to search for phrases such as "***party to the scene***", but I have never used any other computerized databases.

Comment: Search for 'corpus' or 'corpora' here to find many duplicates.

Comment: The OED has over 2 and a half million sentences, including all the possible constructions, idioms, transformations, and usages of every meaningful word in English; typically there are several thousand sentences (all dated and cited) for every word. You can request example searches for any word, up to all examples.

Answer (score 2):

You could include

> "project gutenberg"

in the search terms. [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/) is a repository for old texts that are not copyright. They have several formats to suit the readers' requirements, but they are all released in plain text and html, which makes them searchable.

For your example

> "project gutenberg" "party to the scene"

brings up *The Pagan's Cup* by Fergus Hume (1902), wherein a text search finds

> it was not necessary to hire vehicles to convey the party to the scene of revelry

and other hits. It also has its own search bar.